# Django how to use request data as form in an html template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-auth, django-request

I am using Django rest framework `rest-auth` for login and sign up. But I do not want to use the browseable API as my UI. I am building my own form.

so I am using a custom login url like so:

```
path('rest-auth/customlogin', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
```

where `CustomLoginView` is defined as :

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "api/test_template.html")
```

now in `test_template.html`, I would like to have 2 input fields: `email` and `password`. the same fields that are shown in the browserable API if I did not overwrite with the template.

I am not sure how to get the request data into the template. (if email and password fields reside in the request data, is this correct?)

#### test_template.html

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Login</h3><hr/>
  {# I am not sure how to use input fields here where the data inputted goes in the email and password rest-auth fields#}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a form defined

```
class LoginForm (forms.Form)
    username = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordxInput())
```

add it to your view

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
   form_class = LoginForm
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "api/test_template.html")
```

Then in your template

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.username}}
    {{form.password }}
</form>
```

Comment: what library do I import for this form? `allauth.account.forms` or `django.contib.auth.forms` ? or is it a custom form? in that case how can I implement it?

Comment: since your just learning, put it above your view.  You will need `from django import forms` at the top of the file

Comment: the form is not seen in the template. why is that? also, I am just learning, yes, but eventually this is going to be a live site

Comment: try `form=LoginForm` instead of `form_class`